# How to troubleshoot xdg-desktop-portal in i3 wm?

Tags: firefox, gtk, i3-wm, xdg

I am troubleshooting the known "Firefox cannot open file dialogs" error, with Firefox printing this message on every attempt:
`Gtk-WARNING **: 22:45:36.767: Can't open portal file chooser: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.FileChooser” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop`

I have checked that both `xdg-desktop-portal` and `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` are installed and running:

```sh
$ systemctl --user status xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
● xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service - Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation)
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-07-16 14:35:00 CEST; 8h ago
   Main PID: 258458 (xdg-desktop-por)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 18837)
     Memory: 3.3M
        CPU: 1.207s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service
             └─258458 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gtk

lip 16 14:34:59 carbon systemd[1873]: Starting Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation)...
lip 16 14:35:00 carbon systemd[1873]: Started Portal service (GTK/GNOME implementation).

$ systemctl --user status xdg-desktop-portal
● xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/xdg-desktop-portal.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-07-16 14:13:36 CEST; 8h ago
   Main PID: 229072 (xdg-desktop-por)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 18837)
     Memory: 4.7M
        CPU: 1.419s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/xdg-desktop-portal.service
             └─229072 /usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal

lip 16 14:13:36 carbon systemd[1873]: Starting Portal service...
lip 16 14:13:36 carbon xdg-desktop-por[229072]: No skeleton to export
lip 16 14:13:36 carbon systemd[1873]: Started Portal service.
```

My Ubuntu version:

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

My question is: where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in `/usr/share/xdg-desktop-portal/portals/gtk.portal` and the fact that the session was using i3wm. Changing `UseIn=gnome` to `UseIn=gnome;i3` in that file resolved the problem.

In general, `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` must be in the `UseIn=` stanza in the file. In my case it was `i3`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem for me. I still get `cannot open display` in my journal resulting in heavy hanging and mouse stuttering.

Comment: @Swivel It seems a different problem, I didn't get `cannot open display` but rather `Can't open portal file chooser`

Comment: This didn't solve the issue for me.

Comment: I had the same problem. I followed the solution of Rafał Dowgird and solved the problem. In my case, $ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP ubuntu:GNOME I had to change from `UseIn=gnome` to `UseIn=gnome;unbuntu:GNOME`. I also had given the following command in the process of troubleshooting. sudo apt update sudo apt-get install --reinstall xdg-desktop-portal-gnome xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xdg-desktop-portal-tests xdg-desktop-portal Not sure if the above commands were any useful.